# Unload Userform from another workwook or Add-in

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run some generic code to unload a UserForm from an Add-in. The code below is stored in the added. How do I check the user for a specific  Workbook?

I have been playing around with `VBProject.VBComponents`, but with no joy.

```
Function CheckUnloadForm(ByVal UserFormName As String) As Boolean
Dim objUserForm As Object

CheckUnloadForm = False

For Each objUserForm In VBA.UserForms
  If objUserForm.Name = UserFormName Then
    CheckUnloadForm = True
    Exit For
  End If
Next objUserForm

End Function
```

Comment: What's the use-case here? In other words, why aren't you handling the `Unload` from some module/class where the form is in-scope?

Comment: You don't provide enough information. You need to show us the code that loads the UserForm. In addition: Is the UserForm modal or non-modal? If modal, how do you expect any other code to be able to execute as the Excel application should be blocked, in that case?

Answer (score 0):

This can possibly be done using the Visual Basic Extensibility library that you hinted at. In the `Test` procedure, we loop the open `Workbooks` collection, and for each workbook we loop the `VBComponents`. If there's a component matching the `formName` argument, then we inject some code in to *that* workbook which will `Unload` or `.Hide` the form, and finally we remove the injected code module.

**NB** This can only be done if the form is displayed `vbModeless`.

In your Add-in, create a standard module with the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Public compName As String
Public procName As String

Sub Test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim formName As String
Dim f As Object
formName = "UserForm1"
Dim VBC As Object ' UserForm VBComponent

For Each wb In Workbooks
    For Each VBC In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
        '## If any component matches this name: 
        If VBC.Name = formName Then
            '## Inject some code into wb that will hide/unload the form
            AddCodeToHideUserForm wb, formName
            DoEvents
            '## Call on the Sub that we just injected
            Run procName
            '## Finally, remove the module that we injected into wb.
            RemoveInjectedCode wb, formName
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
Sub RemoveInjectedCode(wb As Workbook, formName As String)
Dim cm As VBComponent
On Error Resume Next
Set cm = wb.VBProject.VBComponents(compName)
wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove cm

End Sub
Sub AddCodeToHideUserForm(wb As Workbook, formName As String, Optional hideInsteadOfUnload As Boolean = False)
Dim code As String
Dim cm As VBComponent
code = "Public Sub hide" & formName & "()" & vbNewLine
code = code & " On Error Resume Next" & vbNewLine
If hideInsteadOfUnload Then
    code = code & formName & ".Hide" & vbNewLine
Else
    code = code & " Unload " & formName & vbNewLine
End If
code = code & "End Sub"
Set cm = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
DoEvents
cm.CodeModule.AddFromString (code)
cm.Name = "Hide" & formName
DoEvents
compName = cm.Name
procName = "'" & wb.Name & "'!" & compName & ".hide" & formName

End Sub
```

Comment: An update to questions asked: The 'Add-In' is used as a generic error code handler for my VBA Code and a few other things, which includes some Userforms. Therefore, it seemed easier to handle the Userform unload within the 'Add-in'. I don't understand the issue of the 'Load' command, the code is performed within each workbook, depending on where the Userform is . Finally, the Userforms are modal. I thought there may be any easy way to unload Userforms without loads of coding, but seems not. Thanks for you comments, I will perhaps stick with adding the unload code in each workbook.

Comment: Well it's simply not possible to do that under any circumstance if the form is modal because when a form is displayed that way the thread is waiting for user input and because Visual Basic is not multi-threaded there's no way to intercept the running thread when the form is displayed